# Expectation of weakly stationary process

Tags: self-study, stochastic-processes, stationarity

Hi all I have a question. Suppose

$$X(t)  = A \cos(t) + B \sin(t)$$

is a weakly stationary process, where $A$ and $B$ are random variables.

Why is it that the mean of $A$ and $B$ are necessarily 0? As I understand it, weak stationarity only requires that the $E(X) = \mathrm{constant}$.

Comment: I've changed the acronym, since this makes the internet the better place :)

Answer (score 1):

Take the expectation of $X(t)$:

$$E \big( X(t) \big) =E (A) \cdot \cos (t) + E(B) \cdot \sin(t)$$

and think what you have on the left hand side (constant), and on the right hand side (real function). Now when the expression on the left hand side is constant **for all** $t$?

Also note that your last statement is incorrect. Weak stationarity requires more than just a constant mean.

Comment: Ah thank you, I get it now, but just an afterthought, since A and B are RV, is it possible that lets' say at t=0, A=1, giving X(1) = 1
and then at say t=2, A=1/cos(2) to give back X(2) = 1
and then for all t, A and B changes such that X(t) = 1, which would still fulfill E(X) = constant?
In such a case, A and B doesn't have to be 0 all the time?

Comment: $A$ and $B$ can't magically change with time to make $X(t)$ constant. That's not how random variables work.